# Uploading a profile picture and displaying it

Tags: php, html

I want users to be able to upload a profile picture (which can be `.jpg` or `.png`) and I also want this to be displayed on their profile. I have written some code, based on sources I found here, on Stackoverflow and Google. However, it does not seem to work and I can't find my mistake.

This is the html

```
        <form action="account_settings.php" method="POST">
            <input type="file" name="profilePicture"><br><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Change!">
        </form>
```

This is how to uploaded file will be processed.

```
<?php
include ('inc/header.inc.php');
if(isset($_FILES["profilePicture"]["tmp_name"]) && isset($_FILES["profilePicture"]["name"])) {
    $ext = pathinfo($_FILES['profilePicture']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    $name = $_SESSION['user_login'];
    $tmp_name = $_FILES["profilePicture"]["tmp_name"];
    if($ext == 'png' || $ext == 'jpg') {
         if (isset($tmp_name)) {
            if(!empty($tmp_name)) {
                $location = '../profielfotos/';
                $full_name = $name.'.'.$ext;
                if(move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $location.$full_name)) {
                    echo 'Photo uploaded!';
                }
                Down here are just some else statements with error reports.
```

The code below is used to display the image. I have tested it by putting an image in the profile pictures folder and it did display the image. However, there is still a problem. People are allowed to upload `.jpg` or `.png`, how can I make the website display the picture (find the profile picture with the right extension).

I have put this code inside the `src` attribute of the `<img>`tag.

```
<?php if ($handle = opendir('profielfotos/')) {
    $file = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['u']);
    echo 'profielfotos/'.$file.'.png'; 
}
closedir($handle);
```

I hope someone can help, thanks in advance!
ps. this is my first post ever on stack overflow :-D!

Comment: - you're missing a very important element in your form.

Comment: - unsure if the session was started.

Comment: - unsure if you are successfully connected using the same API as your escape function.

Comment: Thank you! I added the missing element of my form and it seems to be working now and the session was started in header.inc.php, which you could not know of course.

Comment: you're welcome, but the answer you accepted did not mention about it and in doing so, you're sending out the wrong message. This is especially important for visitors to the question.

Comment: Yes, I see. This is my bad, I asked 2 questions at once actually and the accepted answer is the solution to the second question. I'm new around here and I'm sorry for this. So I should accept the other solution as right answer?

Comment: No leave it, I'll just upvote the other one.

Comment: Alright, I did too but it will only be visible once I reach reputation 15. Thanks again.

Comment: You're welcome and *Welcome to Stack* ;-) cheers

Comment: One last thanks for you, my friend! :-)

Comment: *prego mi amico, ciao!* ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are not storing any info about the file uploaded, you just have check which file exists, using he `file_exists()` method. See here:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php

So your code will become something like this (Not tested):

```
<?php if ($handle = opendir('profielfotos/')) {
    $file = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['u']);
    if (file_exists('profielfotos/'.$file.'.png')) {
        echo 'profielfotos/'.$file.'.png';
    } else if (file_exists('profielfotos/'.$file.'.jpg')) {
        echo 'profielfotos/'.$file.'.jpg';
    }
}
closedir($handle);
```

Comment: Great :-)  Please upvote/accept my answer if it was helpful.

Comment: It was very helpful! I accepted the answer but my upvote will be visible once I hit reputation 15. I'm new around here :-)

Answer (score 3):

You need to add the following to your form:

```
<form action="account_settings.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Otherwise it won't allow a file upload as it expects only text.

Comment: It's so stupid that I actually forgot this, I added it and the code seems to be working now. Thank you!

Comment: @Vallas if that's all it was, then this is the answer that should have been acceptetd and not the other one.

Comment: It seems that the question was a 2-part question. I upvoted this for future visitors to the question.

Answer (score 2):

This is totally insecure. Files uploaded by a user shall never ever be stored within the root of the web server.

Instead, put the files somewhere outside of the doc root.

Write a handler, which takes control of he files

- check the mime type by checking the content, not the extension
- have arbitrary names, not the name from the upload, that might interfer (imagine 5 people uploading a "profile.png")
- let the handler deliver the image by an id ("...imagloader?file=4711"),
- name of the file (and extension and location) is stored in a database (with the user record?)